# How to use the response of a test in JMeter in the request of another test?

Tags: json, jmeter, load-testing

I have 2 tests which have to be run one after the other. The JSON response of the first test contains a field from which I have to extract the value and put it in a file. The second test will read this file and substitute a variable paramter in the JSON request.

For example, if the response of the first test is of the type:

```
{"id":"a1","attr":"b1"}
{"id":"a2","attr":"b2"}
```

The request of the second test is of the form:

```
{"ID":"${A}","ATTR":"B"}
```

So the requests sent should be:

```
{"ID1":"a1","ATTR":"B"}
{"ID2":"a2","ATTR":"B"}
```

for the test.

What I want is to read all the JSON responses first and then use the values in the first field for the value of the `A` parameter of the JSON request of the second test. Is there anyway to do that in JMeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FlexibleFileWriter](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter) to store extracted data to a file and then read it from the second test using e.g. [VariablesFromCSV](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/VariablesFromCSV) or [RawDataSource](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/RawDataSource) plugin or [__CSVRead](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function.

Or you can create one big test (which makes data transfer trivial) that will run those two tests in sequence ([ParameterizedController](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ParameterizedController) can help you parametrise and tidy up this approach).

Answer (score 1):

By 'tests' did you mean requests? If the requests that you want to pass data between are part of the same Thread Group then you can simply use a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).